# Adjust NSDate by one hour for DST

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

My app uses a feed from localendar.com to create a tableview of upcoming events.  The issue though, is that the feeds from localendar do not account for DST, so they end up showing the pubDate of the feed as 1 hour later than the event actually starts.  My app parses the feed and takes the date into the detail line in the cell, which makes it confusing.  I am trying to get my app to detect whether or not the user is in DST, and if they are, subtract one hour from the date.  However, when I use the code below, nothing changes, and a NSLog never gets called on the isDaylightSavingsTime property tag.

UPDATE:

I have tried a different approach in changing it up in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];


    NSString *articleDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:entry.articleDate];
    NSLog(@"after formatter %@", articleDateString);



       cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", articleDateString];
```

The issue is that the time in the RSS feed pubDate does not adjust for DST, so it is an hour off half of the year.  The formatter does everything correct by time zone, because the time in the feed is already wrong as it uses GMT and not US Time.

PLEASE, do NOT vote to close this.  This is not too localized, it applies to every state in the USA that has daylight savings time.

Here are two pics to describe the issue better.  The first shows what is in the RSS Feed, and the second shows what is in the calendar which is the correct time.

[image]

As you see, that time in the feed shows as 10:00, while the actual time that displays every place BUT the RSS feed shows as:

[image]

Update 2:

I tried setting the timezone to Central manually in my code, but it still does the same thing.  In cellForRowAtIndexPath I have:

```
RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Menominee"]]; 
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
       cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", articleDateString];
```

However, instead of getting the detailTextLabel.text to show 5/27/13 10:00 PM, it shows 5/27/13 11:00 PM still.

Comment: NSCalendar has some methods for this

Comment: How is currentTimeZone being initialized?

Comment: @savner `NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [[NSTimeZone alloc] init];`

Comment: check out the update to my question.

Comment: It's going to be hard for people to help without more information about the date you're getting. Can you given an example URL? Or the dates you're getting back which you think are incorrect?

Comment: @JesseRusak The url is http://www.localendar.com/public/timemachinebandagent?style=D4.  As you can see, the first event it shows a time of 10:00.  However, if you view the URL for the calendar at http://www.localendar.com/public/timemachinebandagent it shows the same event on the 24th as starting at 9.  The feed messes it up showing it an hour later, but only during DST, so I need a method to detect when it is DST and if it is, adjust the time from the feed by -1 hours.

Comment: When you read the time from the feed, are you reading the specified time zone as well?  When looking at the RSS feed, it specifically says  "CST".  Are you including the timezone in your date format?  Please update your question with the code used to convert the text from the date/time string into the NSDate.

Answer (score 1):

advise the use of

```
[formatter setTimeZone:localTimeZone];
```

instead.

Comment: Error for use of undeclared identifier localTimeZone

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is that they're showing all dates with "CST" but they are doing the DST correction. CST will never return YES for `isDaylightSavingTime` because that's how it's defined; "Central Time" changes from CST to CDT when daylight savings time comes into effect.

The easiest way to fix this is by ignoring the timezone identifier from the feed and always taking the date as relative to `[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Menominee"]`. (Or some other timezone in Central Time.)

Edit: To be clear, you need to set the time zone of the NSDateFormatter when you're *parsing* the date, not when you're formatting it for display. That is, the change you need to make is not in the code you show.

Comment: The issue is that doing this will make it appear wrong for users in other time zones when DST has ended.

Comment: I don't see how the user's time zone matters. Once you have the correct NSDate, you can format it in whatever time zone you want. Or do you mean for other calendars?

Comment: I'm not following you at all.  Did you look at the feed I posted versus the website where it shows a different time for the feed than it does in the website?

Comment: Yes, I looked at the two examples. For reference, when I access the feed I see "Sun, 26 May 2013 9 pm - 1 am CST" and on the site I see "9:00 PM - 1:00 AM  May 26, 2013"; i.e. the same times, but in different time zones. What I'm saying is that you should set your NSDateFormatter's timeZone to central time and ignore the time zone from the feed. That should give you the correct NSDate when you parse the feed's dates. You can then use another NSDateFormatter to format the result into whatever time zone you want.

Comment: You are incorrect.  Look at the time listed just underneath the event.  Or, click on view page source and see what it lists under pubDate tag.  That time shows as 10:00 and not 9:00.  See the original question to see pics I just added.

Comment: I do not believe I am incorrect. For example, the event on the 27th shows "10:00 PM - 2:00 AM  May 27, 2013" on the site, and "Mon, 27 May 2013 22:00:00 CST" in the pubDate in the RSS source. That is, they are both 10 pm (22:00 == 10 pm), but the RSS feed shows it in the *wrong time zone*, which is what I said above.

Comment: Right, so if it always shows in CST instead of CDT as it is now, then changing the time zone will make it work for these months, but when DST ends later this year it will be wrong by an hour again.

Comment: That's why I'm saying to set the time zone of your parser to "Central Time", which will automatically change from CDT to CST when it should.

Comment: This did not work.  See update 2 in my original post to see what it is still doing.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're saying now.  Current method is `NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"];        
            NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];`  What would be the better way to do this when I parse it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30714/discussion-between-jesse-rusak-and-user717452)