# Parsing RSS Times and DST for iOS NSDate

Tags: ios, rss, nsdate, dst

This is an issue that I have been having for quite some time, and I cannot for the life of me get it fixed properly.  Using the RSS Feed http://www.localendar.com/public/RogerJohnson?style=M3,
I have my app set up to parse the XML and list each calendar entry into the row of a TableView.  The issue pops up when DST begins.  Localendar doesn't have a feature for checking if an event occurs in DST, so in the RSS feed the pubDate always shows as:

```
Fri, 02 May 2014 19:00:00 EST
```

The event for that day actually begins at 7:00 PM EDT.  So, when the app converts everything around, it takes the EST to heart, and knowing it is currently in DST, displays the time as 20:00:00 EDT.  How can I properly set this NSDate so that no matter if it is DST or not, it will show 7:00 instead of adjusting by an hour?

Here is how I am parsing the RSS:

```
 NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"];
            NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];
           NSLog(@"%@", articleDate);
            RSSEntryCalendar *entry = [[[RSSEntryCalendar alloc] initWithBlogTitle:blogTitle articleTitle:articleTitle articleUrl:articleUrl articleDate:articleDate articleImage:bodyoftext] autorelease];
```

Then, displaying in table view I have for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
RSSEntryCalendar *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"]];
    NSString *articleDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:entry.articleDate];


    cell.detailTextLabel.text = articleDateString;
```

As mentioned before, pubDate always shows EST, regardless of DST being in effect or not.  If it shows 19:00:00 it should be 7, regardless of time of year, but is constantly changing during DST.

I put in a NSLog for the NSDate where I parse it, and here is what I get for one entry:

```
2014-05-03 00:00:00 +0000
```

The time that shows up in the table view is `May 2nd, 2014 8:00PM`, while the actual event occurs at `May 2nd, 2014 7:00PM`.  Hopefully this helps to demonstrate issue.

Comment: Please Find this Link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741480/adjust-nsdate-by-one-hour-for-dst

Answer (score 1):

Per [the RSS 2.0 Specification](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification#optionalChannelElements):

> All date-times in RSS conform to the Date and Time Specification of **RFC 822**, with the exception that the year may be expressed with two characters or four characters (four preferred).

Per [RFC 822](http://asg.web.cmu.edu/rfc/rfc822.html#sec-5.1):

```
 zone        =  "UT"  / "GMT"                ; Universal Time
                                             ; North American : UT
             /  "EST" / "EDT"                ;  Eastern:  - 5/ - 4
             /  "CST" / "CDT"                ;  Central:  - 6/ - 5
             /  "MST" / "MDT"                ;  Mountain: - 7/ - 6
             /  "PST" / "PDT"                ;  Pacific:  - 8/ - 7
             /  1ALPHA                       ; Military: Z = UT;
                                             ;  A:-1; (J not used)
                                             ;  M:-12; N:+1; Y:+12
             / ( ("+" / "-") 4DIGIT )        ; Local differential
                                             ;  hours+min. (HHMM)
```

As you can see RFC 822 dates have a very limited set of time zone abbreviations - but they are in the spec and they have very specific meaning.  "EST" = UTC-5.

If the service you're using (Localendar) is erroneously sending back EST when they mean EDT - that's a bug you should take up with them.  They are not properly adhering to the RSS spec.

Working around the bug in your own code is possible - but it's not the best idea:

- One day they might fix it, and then your code could be broken.
- Local times can be ambiguous during the fall-back [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) transition. A value like `"Sun, 2 Nov 2014 01:30:00 EST"` should have a singular meaning, separate from `"Sun, 2 Nov 2014 01:30:00 EDT"`.  By assuming EST=ET, then you have no way to tell these two points apart.